# Which Stack Exchange site is good for asking advice-based questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, off-topic

Recently, I saw many users asking for advice-based questions on Stack Overflow. These questions are getting closed because they are off-topic. Is there any SE site for such users to take advice from experienced people?

For e.g.

- which book is good for Java?

Comment: In a sense, almost *every* question is asking for advice... but it sounds like you're talking about questions which are not concrete enough. Could you provide an example?

Comment: What kind of advice? Beginner stuff, like *"Is it too late learning programming at age 46, and if not, what is the best way to do it"*? or *"Should I go into (learn) [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) (ML) or is it better to go into back-end programming based on [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29) or front-end with [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework))"*? ([Uncle Steff answers such questions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=caTKQr57B8o&t=44m34s)).

Comment: For opinion based stuff, I just ask in the chat room.

Answer (score 7):

If your question is *just* in the form of, "Please give me some technical advice on how to do XYZ", it's going to get closed because none of the technical sites deal with hypothetical circumstances.

The idea behind a question that is well-received on Stack Overflow (or anywhere on the network, really) is that there is a clear and correct answer to the question that is being asked.  If you're not asking a question that is based in that, then your question won't be well received.

To your example, there is no clear or correct answer to "Which book is good for Java", since there can be disagreements on "book", "good" and there's a lot to factor in with respect to your skill level, or what technology you're using.  So *this* kind of question would almost certainly be rejected out-of-hand.